# String storage size in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

After using lots of `SQL Server` and `SQL Server Compact`, I have recently started to use `Sqlite`. I'm currently creating tables in Sqlite and have noticed that there doesn't seem to be any need to input the string length limit when defining string columns. In `SQL Server` a 255-character string datatype is defined like: `varchar(255)`. In `SQL Server Compact` it is defined like: `nvarchar(255)`.

However, in `Sqlite`, it appears that the column datatype can be defined simply as `text`, without inputting any size limit. Is there a way to define a size limit in sqlite? Or is this not even necessary?

Comment: You do not need to specify string column lengths, but you may (see the [syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#type-name)).  However, unlike other DB implementations, fixed-size areas are not allocated for columns, but rather rows are constructed sort of like lists of objects.  So there is no "penalty" for having a wide column that is mostly used for narrow values.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is a managable string or blob limit in SQLite. The default is 10^9 bytes. [See documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)
BTW you don't need to specify it on column declaration anyway.

Answer (score 45):

SQLite does let you write `VARCHAR(255)` or `NVARCHAR(255)`, but the only relevant part of that is `CHAR` (which gives the column "text affinity").  The number in parentheses is allowed for compatibility with standard SQL, but is ignored.

In SQLite, there's little *need* for length constraints on strings, because

1. it doesn't affect the amount of space the string takes up on disk and
2. there's no arbitrary limit (except for `SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH`) on the length of strings that can be used in an `INDEX`.

If you have an actual need to place a limit on the number of characters in a column, just add a constraint like `CHECK(LENGTH(TheColumn) <= 255)`.

Comment: it's good way to store my whole JSON in string format in to SQLite?

Comment: @Arbaz.in I am using that technique to store offline data on my mobile app. Although I am using sqflite (Flutter package for sqlite). But I am splitting the string into multiple shorter ones since the sqlite cursor seems to be having certain limitations when it comes to max read size. Currently I am splitting json into strings of 4096 characters, but I am testing with longer ones at the moment.

Comment: What are the feedback please of this method @miloskarakas ?

Comment: `...it doesn't affect the amount of space the string takes up on disk` how can this be? If I insert a book's worth of text into a table's column, will the database not take up more space on disk than if I inserted a single word?

Comment: @Lukas: Of course it will.  What I mean is that *declaring* a column as `VARCHAR(1000000000)` versus `VARCHAR(255)` does not make a difference in SQLite.  Perhaps I should have worded it better.