# SQLite fixed size varchar length check possibly redundant?

Tags: sqlite, varchar

Let's first have a look at the following table:

```
create table SOME_TABLE_NAME(
    Column varchar(3) primary key check(
        Column glob'[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'
        and length(Column) = 3)
);
```

In our create statement we say that our `Column` consists of not more than characters as maximum. Via glob we check that all 3 characters are letters. Do we still need to check that its length is 3 or is the length check redundant?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COLUMN GLOB '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]'` clause already asserts that primary key consists of exactly three letters, so adding the explicit length check on top of that is redundant.

Comment: Ok awesome, does it make sense to set the column size since varchar is transferred to TEXT?

Comment: Setting the `varchar` width should not make a difference, since `varchar` has an affinity for `text`, and `text` has no real limit, except for `SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH`.  [See this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785047/string-storage-size-in-sqlite) for a discussion on this.